# Reference to different java project source in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I started to use VS Code with Java extension from Rad Hat and I have some problems. For example I want to use interface from another project in workspace but I only found how to add reference to jar libraries, not to source files. It's not a soluiton to make jar file every time I changed one word. I know Idea and Eclipse have this functionality out of the box but I cant find it in vs code. Maybe there are some additional extensions to realize it?

UPD: I was trying to use "java.project.sourcePaths" property in different ways from java.code-workspace.json but I can't see int_proj sources from proj1 in any way.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following configurations in `Workspace Settings.json` and have a try:

```
"java.project.sourcePaths": [
     "path/to/your/soucefolder",
]
```

**[UPDATE]**

Your current working directory is **JAVA(WORKSPACE)**, press `Ctrl+,` and turn to the option `Workspace`, then click the logo[image] to open settings.json, which will generate a folder `.vscode` and settings.json is stored there, then add the above settings. `Clean Java language server workspace` from **Command Palette** then run again:

[image]

Comment: @cusl. The settings.json should be stored in /java(workspace)/.vscode. see my update and hope it solves your question.